# VLC crashs, when watching one specific DVD?

Tags: vlc, dvd

I got some new-ish DVDs to watch. Unfortunately VLC keeps crashing. I set it to Debug mode and got some feedback:

> libdvdnav: Using dvdnav version 6.0.0
>   libdvdnav: DVD Title: LEGEND_OF_KORRA_VOL2
>   libdvdnav: DVD Serial Number: 42da2910
>   libdvdnav: DVD Title (Alternative): 
>   libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00f50000. Regions: 2 4
>
> libdvdread: Attempting to retrieve all CSS keys
>   libdvdread: This can take a *long* time, please be patient
>
> ...
>
> libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_23_1.VOB at 0x003c8185
>   libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
>   libdvdread: Found 23 VTS's
>   libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
>
> *** libdvdread: CHECK_VALUE failed in src/ifo_read.c:906** 
>    **for pgc->cell_playback_offset != 0 ***
>
> *** libdvdread: CHECK_VALUE failed in src/ifo_read.c:906** 
>    **for pgc->cell_playback_offset != 0 ***
>
> libdvdnav: Suspected RCE Region Protection!!!
>   libdvdnav: Suspected RCE Region Protection!!!
>   libva info: VA-API version 1.1.0
>   libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
>   libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
>   libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_1
>   libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
>   Gleitkomma-Ausnahme (Speicherabzug geschrieben)

If I use `dvdsimple://` at least the menu don't crash, but I get 99 titles and all them skip back to the pre-selected title after a while, none plays back fully. On this example Disk are 6 Main titles and some extras, when starting at a main title (title 8 is first main title in this case) and going back to menu to select a different title the same content is played back as in title 8.

Tested Mplayer as well, and get similar problems.

Comment: ere the output of regionset: >regionset version 0.1 -- reads/sets region code on > DVD drives
> Current Region Code settings:
> RPC Phase: II
> type: SET
vendor resets available: 4
user controlled changes resets available: 4
drive plays discs from region(s): 2, mask=0xFD

Answer (score 0):

Try running:

> regionset /dev/dvd

It looks like your hardware is running at a different region code.

Consider that you can change the region code of your DVD drive only a few times.

> How to use the programm
>
> You need write access to the DVD drive, either by group or by being
>   root. The more, there absolutely definitively and in any case *must*
>   be a readable Data CD or Data/Video DVD in the drive -- it does not
>   matter if it's your favourite Windows CD, a video or a DVD with your
>   last backup.
>
> By default, regionset will use /dev/dvd to find your DVD drive. You
>   can adjust this by entering the path to the DVD device as first
>   command line parameter (please absolute path!).
>
> If everything goes well, regionset will show you the current region
>   code of the drive, how often it has been changed and how many changes
>   are left. If there are any changes left, it asks for the new region
>   code (see table above). After confirmation, the new region code will
>   be set -- if you enter the same region code as the current one of the
>   drive or just break the programm, regionset will just exit without
>   setting the new code. On successful change of the region code, you'll
>   get a confirmation.

Are you in Europe (region 2)?

Comment: thanks, region is ok 2 europe is right. not sure why it is reporting 2 and 4 may be that's confusing the debug output, didn't know a DVD can have more than one region only 0 (region free) unfortunately I can't set the drive to 0 as it is too new some older drive were able to be set to 0 and read any disk.

Comment: If you own the DVD you can make a region free backup copy with any DVD transcoder (e.g DVD::Rip, HandBrake DVD Shrink etc.).

Comment: I don't think it is a region lock problem. As I  tried DVD::Rip and Handbreak in copy to my HDD and DVD::Rip only gathers about 40 to 70 % of each title before erroring out about unexpected EOF. I have read over other 99 title DVDs but they are all one long main title so you can guess which title to playback by length.